# Converting a Cartesian ODE to Polar

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polar-coordinates, limit-cycles

I am having trouble trying to convert a first order ODE into polar coordinates.

My ODE system is as follows:

$$\frac{dx}{dt} =y$$

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = -p(x^2+y^2 -1)y - y$$

where $p$ is a parameter such that $p>0$. I know that $r^2=x^2+y^2$, and $\tan \theta=x/y$, but I don't exactly know how to manipulate this ODE to get it to be in the forms of $dr\over dt$ and $d\theta \over dt$.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: $$\frac{d}{dt} \left( r^{2}(t) \right) = \frac{d}{dt} \left( x^{2}(t) + y^{2}(t) \right) \implies 2rr' = 2xx' + 2yy' \implies r' = \frac{xx' + yy'}{\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}}$$ and you know what $x', y'$ are from your ODEs. Similar working yields $\theta'$.

Answer (score 1):

First DE gives us
$$x'=y \implies xx'=yx$$
And from the second DE:
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = -p(x^2+y^2 -1)y - y$$
$$y'y = -p(x^2+y^2 -1)y^2 - y^2$$
Then we have
$$rr'=xx'+yy'$$
$$
\begin{align}
rr'=&xy-p(x^2+y^2 -1)y^2 - y^2 \\
rr'=&r^2\cos \theta \sin \theta-p(r^2 -1)r^2 \sin ^2 \theta - r^2 \sin ^2 \theta \\
r'=&r\cos \theta \sin \theta-p(r^2 -1)r \sin ^2 \theta - r \sin ^2 \theta \\
r'=&r\cos \theta \sin \theta- r \sin ^2 \theta(p(r^2 -1) +1) 
\end{align}
$$
Do the same for $\theta '$
with
$$r^2 \theta '= y'x-x'y$$